Power BI odata.feed: dynamic date filter
I'm not very experienced in creating Power BI datasets so after someone to point me in the right direction please.
I have a connection that pulls back a lot of data across multiple sources. There are 40 different sources, most of which are small amounts of data however, 6 of the sources are large. The returned row count for these sources is between 300,000 and 3.5 million rows. The connection is failing and I'm getting the following error...

Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'There's
not enough memory to complete this operation. Please try again later
when there may be more memory available.

I have applied a date filter to the odata.feed source in an attempt to reduce the amount of data returned...
OData.Feed("https://webaddress.com/sites/SiteName/_api/ProjectData/TimesheetLineActualDataSet?$filter = TimeByDay ge datetime'2024-07-01T00:00:00' and TimeByDay le datetime'2025-06-30T23:59:59'", null, [Implementation="2.0"])

...and only bringing back results from 01/07/24 to 30/06/25. However, I'm still getting the same error (albeit the error is triggered much quicker).

Is the memory error due to the amount of data I'm trying to pull
back?

Will adding date filters to the source help?

Also, is there a way to add a dynamic date filter to the odata.feed? e.g. by something
like...
OData.Feed("https://webaddress.com/sites/SiteName/_api/ProjectData/TimesheetLineActualDataSet
?$filter = TimeByDay ge Add.Months(Now(),-6) and TimeByDay le Add.Months(Now(),6) ", null, [Implementation="2.0"])


I did try changing the Data Load settings - I reduced the Maximum number of simultaneous evaluations to 2, and increased the maximum memory used per simultaneous evaluation to 7097mb.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.
